# Show that $x+1$ is not backward stable

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

> Suppose we use $\oplus$ to compute $x+1$, given $x \in \mathbb{C}$. $\widetilde{f(x)} = \mathop{\text{fl}}(x) \oplus 1$. This algorithm is stable but not backward stable. The reason is that for $x \approx 0$, the addition $\oplus$ will introduce absolute errors of size $O(\epsilon_M)$. Relative to the size of $x$, these errors are unbounded, so they cannot be interpreted as caused by small perturbations in the data.

For a quick notation summary:

- $\epsilon_M$ is machine epsilon that provides an upper bound on relative approximation error.
- $\mathop{\text{fl}}(x)$ is the floating point approximation of $x$. For any $x$, there is some $\epsilon$ such that $\mathop{\text{fl}}(x) = x (1 + \epsilon)$ where ${\lvert \epsilon \rvert} < \epsilon_M$
- $\oplus$ is the floating point approximation of mathematical addition. For any floating point $x,y$ there exists some $\epsilon$ such that $x \oplus y = (x+y)(1 + \epsilon)$ where ${\lvert \epsilon \rvert} < \epsilon_M$
- $\widetilde{f(x)}$ is the algorithmic approximation to $f(x)$

For backward stability we need to show that:

\begin{gather*}
  \forall \vec{x}, \exists \vec{y}:
  \widetilde{f(\vec{x})} = f(\vec{y})
  \; \text{and} \;
  \frac{ {\lVert \vec{x} - \vec{y} \rVert} }{ {\lVert \vec{x} \rVert} } = O(\epsilon_M) \\
\end{gather*}

\begin{align*}
  \widetilde{f(x)} &= \mathop{\text{fl}}(x) \oplus 1
  % = (\mathop{\text{fl}}(x) + 1)(1 + \epsilon_2)
  = (x(1 + \epsilon_1) + 1)(1 + \epsilon_2), \quad {\lvert \epsilon_1 \rvert} < \epsilon_M, {\lvert \epsilon_2 \rvert} < \epsilon_M \\
  &= (x(1 + \epsilon_3) + 1) = y + 1 = f(y), \quad
  \epsilon_3 = O(\epsilon_M) \\
\end{align*}

To show that there exists some $\epsilon_3 = O(\epsilon_M)$ such that $y = x(1 + \epsilon_3)$:

\begin{align*}
  (x(1 + \epsilon_1) + 1)(1 + \epsilon_2) &= (x(1 + \epsilon_3) + 1) \\
  x + x \epsilon_1 + 1 + x \epsilon_2 + x \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_2 &= x + x \epsilon_3 + 1 \\
  x \epsilon_1 + x \epsilon_2 + x \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_2 &= x \epsilon_3 \\
  \epsilon_3 &= \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_2/x \\
\end{align*}

$\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ are both $O(\epsilon_M)$. $\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2$ is $O(\epsilon_M^2)$ and can be discarded. However, $\epsilon_2/x$ is unbounded. so we can't find an $\epsilon_3$ of $O(\epsilon_M)$ satisfying $y = x(1 + \epsilon_3)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is $f(x)=x+1$ not backwards stable if I consider the error propagated in the addition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516155/how-is-fx-x1-not-backwards-stable-if-i-consider-the-error-propagated-in-the)

Comment: Your problem specifies complex numbers, but your analysis is valid for real numbers only. Do you want edit your question/solution to take this into account? Your question is otherwise identical to an old question, see the link.